# GetProduct(string code) method always returns product not found

Tags: c#, ado.net

My GetProduct() method always returns that a product is not found and I have no idea why! I am connected to a database, and I am trying to use the search box on my form to search for an exact product code, and return the code, description, and price.

**Exact instructions:**
Add a static method named GetProduct to the ProductDB class. This method should receive the product code of the product to be retrieved, and it should return a Product object for that product. If a product with the product code isn’t found, this method should return null. Place the code that works with the database in the try block of a try-catch statement, include a catch block that catches and then throws any SqlException that occurs, and include a finally block that closes the connection.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    static Product product = new Product();

    public static Product GetProduct(string code)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = Connection.GetConnection();

        string select = @"SELECT ProductCode, Description, UnitPrice FROM Products WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode";

        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(select, connection);


        SqlParameter pCode = new SqlParameter();
        pCode.ParameterName = "@ProductCode";
        pCode.Value = product.Code;
        SqlParameter pDesc = new SqlParameter();
        pDesc.ParameterName = "@Description";
        pDesc.Value = product.Description;
        SqlParameter pPrice = new SqlParameter();
        pPrice.ParameterName = "@UnitPrice";
        pPrice.Value = product.Price;

        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", code);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader prodReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

            if (prodReader.Read())
            {
                product.Code = prodReader["ProductCode"].ToString(); ;
                product.Description = prodReader["Description"].ToString();
                product.Price = ((decimal)prodReader["UnitPrice"]);

                return product;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Here is the frmProductSearch.cs

```
 private void btnGetProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Validator.IsPresent(txtCode))
        {
            this.GetProduct(txtCode.Text);
            if (product == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No product found with this code. " +
                     "Please try again.", "Product Not Found");
                this.ClearControls();
            }
            else
                this.DisplayProduct();
        }
    }

    private void GetProduct(string code)
    {
        try
        {
            ProductDB.GetProduct(code); // Add a statement here to call the GetProduct method of the ProductDB class.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you step through with a debugger? Also, where are you instantiating `product`?

Comment: What is the value of the `code` variable? Why are you setting up `pCode` and not using it?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `return null;`. Are you hitting it?

Comment: Why isn't `product` defined within this method? Why are you creating all those other parameters? Especially another one for `@ProductCode`

Comment: You're calling `GetProduct`, but not returning the results of the method. Please step through this code with a debugger, I guarantee that will lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Is there a different `static product` defined in both classes? Instead of using a private static field, you should just return the `Product` from the method. I have a feeling that you're setting the `static Product` in your `ProductDb` class, but trying to access a different one in your `frmProductSearch` class.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably get rid of any `private static Product product` fields you have. I think this may be what's causing you confusion because it appears that you're referencing one in your `ProductDB` class and a different one in your `frmProductSearch` class. If this is the case, that would explain why you're getting null - because the `ProductDB` class never touches the static field of the `frmProductSearch` class (and it shouldn't).

You should simply have all your methods return a `Product`, and have the calling methods use the returned value rather than relying on a static field to get updated.

So, to modify your code a little, your 'ProductDB' method should return a new product:

```
public static Product GetProduct(string code)
{        
    try
    {                        
        SqlConnection connection = Connection.GetConnection();

        string select = @"SELECT ProductCode, Description, UnitPrice " + 
            "FROM Products WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode";

        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(select, connection);
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", code);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader prodReader = 
            selectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

        if (prodReader.Read())
        {
            return new Product
            {
                Code = prodReader["ProductCode"].ToString(),
                Description = prodReader["Description"].ToString(),
                Price = (decimal) prodReader["UnitPrice"]
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Your form method can now consume the return value of this method directly, and pass it along:

```
private Product GetProduct(string code)
{
    // Add a statement here to call the GetProduct method of the ProductDB class.
    return ProductDB.GetProduct(code); 
}
```

Finally, you can consume the returned product in your other form method and pass it to your `DisplayProduct` method:

```
private void btnGetProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Validator.IsPresent(txtCode))
    {
        Product product = this.GetProduct(txtCode.Text);

        if (product == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No product found with this code. Please try again.", 
                "Product Not Found");

            this.ClearControls();
        }
        else
        {
            this.DisplayProduct(product);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this means you'll need to update your `DisplayProduct` method to take in the parameter and use that instead of a static field:

```
private static void DisplayProduct(Product product)
{
    // Implementation here...
}
```